# How to install with a damaged disc?

Tags: xbox-360

Disc 1 is in bad shape. I would like to know if am able to copy disk 1 onto a USB drive or download it. I tried installing a few times and it seems to always get halfway through and then it just does nothing.

I have tried cleaning the disc with toothpaste and petroleum jelly without much luck.

If anyone could help me out and let me know what you think I should do, it would help me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## DO NOT to clean discs with toothpaste and petroleum jelly you're just going to make it worse.

**You must resurface the disc using wet sand paper and rubbing compound.**

1. Get an assorted pack of 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000-7000 grit wetordry sandpapers, 3M rubbing compound, and a good quality microfiber cloth/auto buffing tool. (Preferably buffing pad used for auto)
2. Clean disc with glass cleaner. Wet sand your disc from 1000 all the way to 7000. You have to wet sand. That means you make the sandpaper wet and rub the disc. Don't over do it. Look at the video below for reference.
3. Apply 3M rubbing compound to disc and rub with microfiber/buffing tool.
4. Clean disc with glass cleaner. Try to play game.
5. If your game does not play repeat steps 1-4.

Source:

*You can use whatever brand you want but I trust 3M.*
[image]

[image]